# node.js walk path variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, npm

I currently have a problem with the npm package "walk", the problem is that the path it is supposed to take can only be given with a string. This is a problem because the path will change depending on what directory it should search in.

```
var walkers = walk.walk(""+animeDir+"", options);
walkers.on('file', function(root, stat, next) {
    files.push(stat.name);
    next();
});
```

I have tried different ways such as:

```
var walkers = walk.walk("F:/" + animeDir, options);
var walkers = walk.walk("\"animeDir\"", options); // "F:/" was already included
var walkers = walk.walk("'+animeDir+'", options);
```

and lastly just by passing the variable itself, though I get some error like:`binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), req);
TypeError: path must be a string.`
I am currently running out of ideas and I have not found something that has been of help. I look forward for you answers, thank you in advance!

Comment: What's `animeDir`? Also, have you tried [`path.join`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `animeDir` (and `options`) is a javascript variable defined above like

```
var animeDir = 'F:/AnimeMovies';
```

The first parameter of the `walk.walk(dir, options);` function is required to be a string (like the variable defined above) to properly pass a string as a variable you don't need the `""+var+""` try:

```
var walkers = walk.walk(animeDir, options);
```

The correct way to concatenate strings to your string variable is with `+`:

```
var walkers = walk.walk( animeDir + '\', options);
```

If you are trying to pass the string literally right there try this:

```
var walkers = walk.walk("F:/animeMovies/videos/", options);
```

Have you tried this to find any errors that are happening after successfully calling `walk.walk(dir, options);`?

```
  walkers.on('errors', function(root, nodeStatsArray, next) {
  nodeStatsArray.forEach(function (n) {
    console.error("[ERROR] " + n.name)
    console.error(n.error.message || (n.error.code + ": " + n.error.path));
  });
  next();
}
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer, but I fixed it just 15 minutes ago. The problem was that my "walk" function ran before animeDir could be given a value which would lead to animeDir = undefined. I fixed this by running my "walk" function inside my route AFTER animeDir has been given a value. But you have my thanks for even giving me some of your time!

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution! Glad you figured it out, yep node's async processing can be fickle in that way, you have to know what is defined in what scopes when etc. Good job!